# Actionbutton and observeEvent not working (R shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

Can somebody check the code below for me and tell me what's wrong?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("Mean",
        label="Drag to select the mean of the normal distribution",
        min=0,max=5,value=0),
        actionButton("show","Go")
    ),
    mainPanel(
                h3("The number is"),
                textOutput('number')
    )   
  )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    #observeEvent(input$show, {
        #output$number <- round(rnorm(as.numeric(input$mu)), 2)
     #}) 

    output$number <- eventReactive(input$show, {
        round(rnorm(as.numeric(input$mu)), 2)
    })
    }
)
```

Just want to have a random number sampled from a normal distribution with a given mean each time I click 'Go'. Neither eventReactive nor observeEvent worked.

Answer (score 3):

I'n not a big fan of having objects inside `observeEvent` so here is the solution with `eventReactive`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("Mean",label="Drag to select the mean of the normal distribution",min=0,max=5,value=0),
      actionButton("show","Go")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3("The number is"),
      textOutput('number')
    )   
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- eventReactive(input$show, {
    round(rnorm(as.numeric(input$Mean)), 2)
  })

  output$number <- renderText({
    data()
  })

}
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `eventReactive` is a reactive variable. You will need to use `renderText` and `observeEvent`. Also you have not defined `input$mu` in your ui, I think it should be `input$Mean`

After implementing the above modifications your server code should be something like this:

```
 server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

           observeEvent(input$show, {
           output$number <- renderText(round(rnorm(as.numeric(input$Mean)), 2))
           })

         }
         )
```

Hope it helps!